# Table with student grades and average, in PHP and HTML, without Db, method for adding students

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table, constructor

I need to implement a table with student grades. From these classes.

[image: Class Class and Student]

The project I'm trying to do is very simple, only 3 files: index.php, Student.php and Class.php

There must be a method that adds a maximum of 5 student objects. Therefore, this function must return a boolean value for success and false for error. Here I am trying the if else.
In the class class, I want to create an attribute that stores the class name by the constructor method.

I have the code below (PHP and HTML):

Aluno.php

```
<?php
abstract class Aluno
{
    protected $nome, $RA, $nota1, $nota2, $nota3, $nota4;
}

private function setNome($nome):bool
{
    if(is_string($nome)){
        $this->nome = $nome;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}
  
private function setRA($RA):bool
{
    if(is_int($RA)){
        $this->RA = $RA;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}

private function setNota1($nota1):bool{
    if(is_double($nota1)){
        $this->nota1 = $nota1;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}

private function setNota2($nota2):bool
{
    if(is_double($nota2)){
        $this->nota2 = $nota2;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}

private function setNota3($nota3):bool
{
    if(is_double($nota3)){
        $this->nota3 = $nota3;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}

private function setNota4($nota4):bool
{
    if(is_double($nota4)){
        $this->nota4 = $nota4;
        return true;
    } else 
        return false;
}

abstract public function exibirDados();
}
```

?>

Turma.php

```
 <?php
 require_once('Aluno.php');
  
class Turma extends Aluno
{
    protected $alunos[];
    function __construct($classname)
    {
        $this->setClassname($classname);
    }
    
    private function setAlunos($alunos):bool
    {
        if(is_string($alunos)){
            $this->alunos = $alunos;
            return true;
        } else 
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I need to Instantiate 5 objects for the student class, and through a method add the values for each object, and then insert the object into an array of students, and Instantiate the Class Class, and add the student objects that are in the array students. At this point, you must validate if 5 students have already been registered and print the success or error when inserting the student in the class.

The data contained in the table are those in the figure below.
This goes in index.php. I don't know how to do this index.

[image: Student table on index.php]

In summary: maximum 5 students later show error (in red) show class average. Show the five students with their grades and the average for each student. Simple but not for me, I'm trying a lot but it's hard. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I understand the assignment but not what you need help with. Do you only need help with instantiating the 5 student objects and adding them to the class? Where are you validating that a max of 5 students can be added? Where are you adding them? Are those private functions (ex. `private function setNome($nome)`) sitting _outside_ of a class or is that just bad formarring?

Comment: You're also calling an undefined method in your constructor: `$this->setClassname(...);`

Comment: I don't know how do add the students, and limit this to 5

Comment: and how to show on screen , the table, is this with echo?

Comment: Tks RiggsFolly for help with edit post.